# Update duplicate data based on the first one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

can anyone help me about my problem, so I want to make a query with which I can update the data that is double, for example: I have data with the same B.OTO_ID, and one of them correctly enter the VLI_OMDF_ID data while with another NULL, I want to say for all the data in sql that if there are two data with the same B.OTO_ID but RACK is the other NULL code, I will UPDATE it the same as the first.

see please picture

[image]

So I need to update the table VL_Liegenschaften column VLI_OMDF_ID
if there are two VLW_OTOID in the VL_Wohneinheiten table of which one is VLI_OMDF_ID for null

I hope you understand me, thank you very much for your help

```html
merge into VL_Liegenschaften
using(select VL_Wohneinheiten.VLW_Liegenschaft, t.VLI_OMDF_ID
from (
    select VL_Liegenschaften.VLI_ID, VL_Liegenschaften.VLI_OMDF_ID, VL_Wohneinheiten.VLW_OTOID
     from VL_Liegenschaften
     join VL_Wohneinheiten on VL_Wohneinheiten.VLW_Liegenschaft = VL_Liegenschaften.VLI_ID
    where VL_Liegenschaften.VLI_OMDF_ID IS NOT NULL
     ) t
    join VL_Wohneinheiten on t.VLW_OTOID = VL_Wohneinheiten.VLW_OTOID) t
on (t.VLW_Liegenschaft = VL_Liegenschaften.VLI_ID
    and VL_Liegenschaften.VLI_OMDF_ID IS NULL)
when matched then 
    update set VL_Liegenschaften.VLI_OMDF_ID = t.VLI_OMDF_ID 
;
```

This is my query unfortunately I can not enforce it.

[image]

error messages:

The MERGE statement tried to update or delete the same row more than once. This happens when a target line matches more than one source line. A MERGE statement can not repeatedly update / delete the same row of the target table. Optimize the ON clause to ensure that a target row matches at least one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

**my table is the same as yours, you just made it VLW_Liegenschaft twice, and my link is made via tbl1 VLW_Liegenschaft to tbl2 VLI_ID

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: @jarlh it's clear to me, but I have to show people somehow what exactly I need

Comment: @Michael I think jarlh is implying that you should copy the values from SQL Server Management Studio in to your question, as text and not images.

Comment: [Here is why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) images are not a good way to post data and information.

Comment: Just to check, you want to update the `NULL` in column `CLI_OMDF_ID` ,for row `VLI_ID = 59806`, to be the same as in row `VLI_ID = 60001`?  Because they share the same `VLW_OTOID` in the first table?  Is it possible for three or more rows in the first table to have the same `VLW_OTOID`?  And if so, what do you want to happen then?  *(The NULL could become either of two different nonNULL values...)*

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well you can do something like this, using a self join on OTO_ID to get the value.

```
declare @tbl as table (
    OTO_ID varchar(15)
    ,VLI_OMDF_ID varchar(15)
);

insert into @tbl values ('a18d5', 'hhgg'), ('a18d5', NULL), ('asasad', 'ffff'), ('asasad', NULL);


update t
    set t.VLI_OMDF_ID = t2.VLI_OMDF_ID
from @tbl t
inner join @tbl t2
    on t.OTO_ID = t2.OTO_ID
where t.VLI_OMDF_ID is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

In absence of replies to my comment, this may only be part of the way to what you want...

```
WITH
  expanded_VL_L AS
(
  SELECT
    L.*,
    W.VLW_OTOID,
    MAX(L.VLI_OMDF_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY W.VLW_OTOID)   AS MAX_VLI_OMDF_ID
  FROM
    VL_L  AS L
  INNER JOIN
    VL_W  AS W
      ON W.VLW_L = L.VLI_ID
)
UPDATE
  expanded_VL_L
SET
  VLI_OMDF_ID = MAX_VLI_OMDF_ID
WHERE
  VLI_OMDF_ID IS NULL
```

As you can see in the example below, this finds the `MAX()` of all associated rows and replaces the `NULL` with that `MAX()`.

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5ef9bbcb8518e55a7e6aabd5ef3a7849

If that's not what you want, please do update you original post.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help:

```
create table t1(VL_Liegenschaften nvarchar(128), VLW_OTOID nvarchar(128), VLI_OMDF_ID nvarchar(128))

create table t2(VL_Liegenschaften nvarchar(128), VLI_OMDF_ID nvarchar(128))

insert into t1
values('59806', 'B.178.002', 'FRA_11'), ('60001', 'B.178.002', null), ('69001', 'B.178.002', null)

insert into t2
values('59806', 'FRA_11'), ('60001', null), ('69001', null)

merge into t2
using(select t.VL_Liegenschaften, t1.VLI_OMDF_ID 
    from t1 
    join t1 as t on t1.VLW_OTOID = t.VLW_OTOID
    where t.VLI_OMDF_ID is null) t
on (t.VL_Liegenschaften = t2.VL_Liegenschaften 
    and t.VLI_OMDF_ID IS NOT NULL)
when matched then 
    update set t2.VLI_OMDF_ID = t.VLI_OMDF_ID 
;
```

**UPDATE:** update after a condition clarifying

if there is no `VLI_OMDF_ID` column in the first table:

```
create table t1(VL_Liegenschaften nvarchar(128), VLW_OTOID nvarchar(128))

create table t2(VL_Liegenschaften nvarchar(128), VLI_OMDF_ID nvarchar(128))

insert into t1
values('59806', 'B.178.002'), ('60001', 'B.178.002'), ('69001', 'B.178.002'), ('79001', 'C.718.002'), ('79002', 'C.718.002')

insert into t2
values('59806', 'FRA_11'), ('60001', null), ('69001', null), ('79001', 'USA_01'), ('79002', null)

merge into t2
using(select t1.VL_Liegenschaften, t.VLI_OMDF_ID
from (
    select t2.VL_Liegenschaften, t2.VLI_OMDF_ID, t1.VLW_OTOID
     from t2 
     join t1 on t1.VL_Liegenschaften = t2.VL_Liegenschaften
    where t2.VLI_OMDF_ID IS NOT NULL
     ) t
    join t1 on t.VLW_OTOID = t1.VLW_OTOID) t
on (t.VL_Liegenschaften = t2.VL_Liegenschaften
    and t2.VLI_OMDF_ID IS NULL)
when matched then 
    update set t2.VLI_OMDF_ID = t.VLI_OMDF_ID 
;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, your answer best suits me, I just do not have in both tables VLI_OMDF_ID, I have only one, and I compare tables based on VL_Liegenschften and VLV_OTOID, and if I have VLW_OTOID with id VL_Liegenschaften in another table somewhere NULL, I need to set VLI_OMDF_ID as well as for the first one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, can you look at my question corrected, I worked for your case, but unfortunately there is a run error

Comment: @Michael sorry but I can't  reproduce any errors on my test data and on your last screen VL_Wohneinheiten.VLW_Liegenschaft and  VL_Liegenschaften.VLI_ID doesn't match at all. So I don't understand how do you want to merge them? Could you please add a full error message into the question?

Comment: I have corrected my question, thank you very much, this really means a lot to me

Comment: @Michael I've read your previous screen more closely and now I am sure that it is impossible to achive what you want in a current data structure. The problem is that in a VL_Wohneinheiten you have records with a same VLW_Liegenschaft but with different VLW_OTOID but you want to merge it with VL_Liegenschaften table by only one filed VLW_Liegenschaft <-> VLI_ID. And It is the reason which leads to the error.

Comment: I do not have the same VLW_OTOID for me, but for that VLW_OTOID I have some VLI_OMDF_ID and I have some I do not have, and I want those who already have VLI_OMDF_ID to assign them to others who have the same VLW_OTOID

Comment: Look at your screen: 
row#3: VLW_Liegenschaft = 52455, VLW_OTOID=B.176.001.450.08
row#4: VLW_Liegenschaft = 52455, VLW_OTOID=B.176.001.451.06
And a join goes by VLW_Liegenschaft  <-> VLI_ID
We have at least TWO identical VLW_Liegenschaft for different VLW_OTOID
The first record in a merge statement will be taken by a VLW_OTOID=B.176.001.450.08 and the second one by VLW_OTOID=B.176.001.451.06 and since they have the same VLW_Liegenschaft  it will lead to the error while merging